# How to get google adwords reports in salesforce?

Tags: apex, callout, soap, http

Hi I am developing application in salesforce for accessing the google adwords reports data for e.g. ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT. I am sending http post request to https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/reportdownload/v201302, and I am using apex(java like language in salesforce) below is my request.

```
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
GoogleAuthorization auth=new GoogleAuthorization();
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'GoogleLogin ' + auth.token);
req.setHeader('UserAgent', 'XXXXX');
req.setHeader('developerToken','XXXXXXXX');
req.setHeader('clientCustomerId','XXXXXXXX');
req.setEndPoint('https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/reportdownload/v201302');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req.setMethod('POST');
string xml='<reportDefinition xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201302">'+
          '<selector>'+
            '<fields>CampaignId</fields>'+
            '<fields>Id</fields>'+
            '<fields>Impressions</fields>'+
            '<fields>Clicks</fields>'+
            '<fields>Cost</fields>'+
            '<predicates>'+
              '<field>Status</field>'+
              '<operator>IN</operator>'+
              '<values>ENABLED</values>'+
              '<values>PAUSED</values>'+
            '</predicates>'+
          '</selector>'+
          '<reportName>Custom Adgroup Performance Report</reportName>'+
          '<reportType>ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT</reportType>'+
          '<dateRangeType>LAST_7_DAYS</dateRangeType>'+
          '<downloadFormat>XML</downloadFormat>'+
        '</reportDefinition>';
req.setBody('__rdxml='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(xml, 'UTF-8'));
HttpResponse res=h.send(req);
```

After requesting i am getting the AuthenticationError System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400].

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><reportDownloadError><ApiError><type>AuthenticationError.USER_ID_INVALID</type><trigger>&lt;null&gt;</trigger><fieldPath></fieldPath></ApiError></reportDownloadError>
```

Comment: Hi SFIntegrator. Were you able to get this integrated? Would you mind posting your solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not forming a valid SOAP request - Your issue is not an Apex code one but a SOAP one.

I haven't tested this solution myself but Salesforce has the functionality to [build apex classes from WSDLs](http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/code_wsdl_to_package.htm), try using the [AdWords WSDL](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201302/CampaignService) to generate a class.